# filling missing rows with currency

Tags: postgresql, sisense

I have the following table (with different currencies):

| date | currency | ex_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.8347245409015025 |
| 27/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.8387854386847845 |
| 26/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.84033613445378152 |

As you can see, there is some missing data for two dates. I would like to fill it with the previous available date, so it would be like this:

| date | currency | ex_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.8347245409015025 |
| 29/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.8387854386847845 |
| 28/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.8387854386847845 |
| 27/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.8387854386847845 |
| 26/11/2020 00.00 | USD | 0.84033613445378152 |

Or redirect me to a question of the same kind

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_series` to build the series of dates from the earlierst and later values available in the table, then bring the corresponding rows with a lateral join:

```
select d.dt, 'USD', t.ex_rate
from (
    select generate_series(min(date), max(date), interval '1 day') as dt
    from mytable
    where currency = 'USD'
) d
cross join lateral (
    select t.*
    from mytable t 
    where currency = 'USD' and t.date <= d.dt
    order by t.date desc limit 1
) t
```

I wonder whether a `left join` on date equality and then some window function technique to build groups of records might be more efficient:

```
select dt, 'USD', max(ex_rate) over(partition by grp) as ex_rate
from (
    select d.*, t.*,
        count(t.date) over(order by d.dt) as grp
    from (
        select generate_series(min(date), max(date), interval '1 day') as dt
        from mytable
        where currency = 'USD'
    ) d
    left join mytable t on currency = 'USD' and t.date = d.dt
) t
```

Note that this can easily be generalized to handle all currencies at once:

```
select dt, currency, max(ex_rate) over(partition by currency, grp) as ex_rate
from (
    select d.dt, c.currency, t.ex_rate,
        count(t.date) over(partition by c.currency order by d.dt) as grp
    from (select distinct currency from mytable) c
    cross join (
        select generate_series(min(date), max(date), interval '1 day') as dt
        from mytable
    ) d
    left join mytable t on t.currency = c.currency and t.date = d.dt
) t
```

Comment: i got the following 
ERROR: function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, "unknown") does not exist

Comment: @enriqueqs: I added an explicit cast for the interval (although this should not be a problem in Postgres).

Comment: yeah, my bad. I am working on redshift for this query (I use both and get mixed up sometimes)